# Canvas figures moves to the right side

Tags: javascript, canvas

Here is the code:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var canvas = $("#canvas")[0];
  var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
  canvas.width = window.innerWidth
  canvas.height = window.innerHeight
  polygon(context, 120, 120, 50, 12);
  context.stroke();
})

function polygon(ctx, x, y, radius, sides) {
  if (sides < 3) return;
  var a = ((Math.PI * 2) / sides);
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.translate(x, y);
  ctx.moveTo(radius, 0);
  for (var i = 1; i < sides; i++) {
    ctx.lineTo(radius * Math.cos(a * i), radius * Math.sin(a * i));
  }
  ctx.closePath();
}
```

```html
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<canvas id="canvas">OOPS.. Upgrade your Browser</canvas>
```

This code works fine. BUT each of my polgon appears at wrong place. For example I call

```
polygon(context, 120,120,50,12);
```

and

```
polygon(context, 120,220,50,12);
```

and the second polygon appears at `x=220, y=220`

I mean, they moves in the right side, but they should appear one under another with the same `x` coordinates.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After drawing the shape you need to [`translate`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/translate) it back to the original position so the next shape is drawn from the same relative location as the first.

```
ctx.translate(-x, -y);
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var canvas = $("#canvas")[0];
  var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
  canvas.width = window.innerWidth
  canvas.height = window.innerHeight
  polygon(context, 120, 120, 50, 12);
  context.stroke();
  polygon(context, 120,220,50,12);
  context.stroke();
})

function polygon(ctx, x, y, radius, sides) {
  if (sides < 3) return;
  var a = ((Math.PI * 2) / sides);
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.translate(x, y);
  ctx.moveTo(radius, 0);
  for (var i = 1; i < sides; i++) {
    ctx.lineTo(radius * Math.cos(a * i), radius * Math.sin(a * i));
  }
  ctx.closePath();
  ctx.translate(-x, -y);
}
```

```html
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<canvas id="canvas">OOPS.. Upgrade your Browser</canvas>
```

Answer (score 1):

Reset the translation matrix to the identity matrix before drawing each shape:

```
context.setTransform(1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0);
```

Answer (score 1):

I think it happens because of:

```
ctx.translate(x, y);
```

If you look closely at [HTML canvas translate() Method](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/canvas_translate.asp) *Definition and Usage* you will see that translate() method remaps the (0,0) position of the canvas instead of setting starting point for your drawing. So if you do function call like this:

```
ctx.translate(120, 120);
ctx.translate(120, 220);
```

You actually moving registration point of canvas twice. First time it will be moved by (120,120) and later it will be moved by (120,220), so your first polygon will be drawed correctly but the second will be drawed on position (240,340), because coordinates of both starting points will eventually be summed.

Answer (score 0):

You are using the same 2d context over and over for your polygons. The context will save the state of your translations, so consecutive translations add up. You could "revert" the effect of translations by translating with same-negative-values at the end of each `polygon` call.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var canvas = $("#canvas")[0];
  var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
  canvas.width = window.innerWidth
  canvas.height = window.innerHeight
  polygon(context, 120, 120, 50, 12);
  context.stroke();
  polygon(context, 120, 220, 50, 12);
  context.stroke();
})

function polygon(ctx, x, y, radius, sides) {
  if (sides < 3) return;
  var a = ((Math.PI * 2) / sides);
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.translate(x, y);
  ctx.moveTo(radius, 0);
  for (var i = 1; i < sides; i++) {
    ctx.lineTo(radius * Math.cos(a * i), radius * Math.sin(a * i));
  }
  ctx.closePath();
  ctx.translate(-1 * x, -1 * y);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<canvas id="canvas">OOPS.. Upgrade your Browser</canvas>
```